# mondrian.olap.ResourceLimitExceededException: Mondrian Error:Number of members to be read exceeded limit (10,000)

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I have a problem similar to the one reported on the Pentaho blog in the post below:

https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/47819-Help-regd-member-restriction/?p=141499

And that query is very simple:

```
MDX: SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[QTD_EMPRESAS]} on 0, NON EMPTY {[BAIRRO.BAIRRO_H].[TODOS_BAIRRO_H],[BAIRRO.BAIRRO_H].[06], [BAIRRO.BAIRRO_H].[061]} on 1 FROM [V_DM_EMPRESAS_LOCALIDADE] WHERE {[BAIRRO_F.BAIRRO_H].[06],[BAIRRO_F.BAIRRO_H].[061]}
```

If i use one filter it is return successfully, but with two filter, like the query above error occurs. Both filters together add up to 200 records, less than the limit reported in the error.

The dimension BAIRRO have more than 10000 records, but i filter only two BAIRRO.

Error occurred:

```
Caused by: mondrian.olap.ResourceLimitExceededException: Mondrian Error:Number of members to be read exceeded limit (10,000)
    at mondrian.resource.MondrianResource$_Def11.ex(MondrianResource.java:1180)
    at mondrian.rolap.SqlMemberSource.getMemberChildren2(SqlMemberSource.java:993)
    at mondrian.rolap.SqlMemberSource.getMemberChildren(SqlMemberSource.java:891)
    at mondrian.rolap.SqlMemberSource.getMemberChildren(SqlMemberSource.java:864)
    at mondrian.rolap.NoCacheMemberReader.getMemberChildren(NoCacheMemberReader.java:179)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapCubeHierarchy$NoCacheRolapCubeHierarchyMemberReader.readMemberChildren(RolapCubeHierarchy.java:970)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapCubeHierarchy$NoCacheRolapCubeHierarchyMemberReader.getMemberChildren(RolapCubeHierarchy.java:1027)
    at mondrian.rolap.NoCacheMemberReader.getMemberChildren(NoCacheMemberReader.java:159)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaReader.internalGetMemberChildren(RolapSchemaReader.java:186)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaReader.getMemberChildren(RolapSchemaReader.java:169)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaReader.getMemberChildren(RolapSchemaReader.java:162)
    at mondrian.olap.DelegatingSchemaReader.getMemberChildren(DelegatingSchemaReader.java:78)
    at mondrian.olap.fun.AggregateFunDef$AggregateCalc.getChildCount(AggregateFunDef.java:571)
    at mondrian.olap.fun.AggregateFunDef$AggregateCalc.optimizeMemberSet(AggregateFunDef.java:490)
    at mondrian.olap.fun.AggregateFunDef$AggregateCalc.optimizeChildren(AggregateFunDef.java:398)
    at mondrian.olap.fun.AggregateFunDef$AggregateCalc.optimizeTupleList(AggregateFunDef.java:252)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapResult.<init>(RolapResult.java:314)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.executeInternal(RolapConnection.java:662)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.access$000(RolapConnection.java:52)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection$1.call(RolapConnection.java:613)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection$1.call(RolapConnection.java:611)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

To avoid this bug, in the Mondrian schema, I configured Role and in the HierarchyGrant configuration i am setting rollupPolicy to false.

Is this really a good strategy? Or is there a better one?

Answer (score 0):

Role and Hierarchy grants are for security so I wouldn't set those unless you need them for data access control.

It looks like your mondrian.result.limit configuration setting is set too low at 10,000.  For optimizing Mondrian performance, I would start with this mondrian.properties and tweak settings from there:

https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-platform/blob/master/assemblies/pentaho-solutions/src/main/resources/pentaho-solutions/system/mondrian/mondrian.properties

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I adjusted the mondrian.properties according to your orientation, but there is still an error to execute the query. Some queries generate a timeout error. With the error stacktrace, and debugging, I understood that the problem occurs when calculating the total column, where a query is executed for each record of the dimension, which overcomes the limit of queries or timeout. Is there any configuration in the cube schema that can help? Especially as the total column?

Comment: I'd have to see your stack trace to know what the problem was.  Queries can timeout for many reasons including slow SQL, too many cells, complex MDX expressions, mondrian.properties settings etc.   You can try playing around with the cell batch size (please see the comment in there) to tweak the Segment.load queries.  FYI, Pentaho 9.2 will include many query plan execution and logging improvements to aid with debugging performance problems.